# Can I improve this query/code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Thred model which has many users through posts.

I fetch all threds, `@threds = Thred.all` and then `render @threds` in my index template.

However I check whether the current user has replied in each of the threds, using:

```
if member && thred.user_posted?(current_user)
```

Which utilizes the following method:

```
  def user_posted?(user)
    users = []
    self.users.map { |u| users << u.id }
    users.include?(user.id)
  end
```

It works, but I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a [codereview.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  def user_posted?(user)
    user_ids = self.users.pluck(:id)
    user_ids.include?(user.id)
  end
```

or

```
  def user_posted?(user)
    self.users.where(id: user.id).any?
  end
```

Comment: You could use `exists?` instead of `any?` to get possibly better SQL. I don't know if it is worth it though.

Comment: Thank you both - I went with ```exists?``` as the ```any?``` query does a select count (and I'm guessing that's slower? They both appear to be executed roughly the same time in console).

Comment: Native ruby methods are faster than Rails methods unless there is additional SQL query. It will also affect memory consumption.

Comment: Right thanks, I have changed it to ```any?``` :-)